# Weird characters on angular ajax error response

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript

Hello guys I have a problem when an error occurs I can't see the content of response. Debugging, I notice that the error looks encoded like you can see in the img, how could I handle this? any hint or suggestion are welcome, thanks. 
[image]

this is my ajax code.

```
    SelectItemsFromInbox(selectedItems: InboxItem[], initialDate: Date, finalDate: Date, travelState: string)
{
    let reqOptions: {} = this.requestUtils.createHeaders();

    return this.http.post('InboxApi/SelectItemsFromInbox', {
        selectedItems: selectedItems,
        initialDate: initialDate.toISOString(),
        finalDate: finalDate.toISOString(),
        travelState: travelState
    }, reqOptions)
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => <InboxItem[]>res.json())
        .then(data => { return data; })
        .catch(data => {
            console.log(data);
            debugger;
            this.messageService.add ({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error!', detail: 'Algo salio mal contacte al administrador' });
            return null;
        });        
}
```

Comment: Could you post the response of the SelectedItemsFromInbox service? feels like is returning an image or a file.

Comment: looks like binary data you probably need some Array Buffer for handling this

Comment: Please share the implementation of your `this.requestUtils.createHeaders();` as well. The response that you receive significantly depends on the `responseType` option as well. By default, it generally is `json` but you might have set it to `blob`